# AWS Cognito: what the url for refreshing of token_id (AdminInitiateAuth)?

Tags: amazon-cognito

On my web-browser client I need to renew `token_id` using `refresh_token` from Cognito. In the [documentation page about using of tokens](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html) I found the link to the documentation of the method [AdminInitiateAuth](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminInitiateAuth.html) - but this is only for js sdk. I want to keep my webapp fast and only for one http call I do not want to introduce a dependency library.

Comment: It is not clear how you're interacting with Cognito to get the id token in the first place. Can you clarify that?

Comment: Hosted ui returned `code` -> on backend exchanged to `id_token`, `access_token` and `refresh_token`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hit the token endpoint with a grant type of refresh_token and the refresh token:

```
POST https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token >
Content-Type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
Authorization=Basic aSdxd892iujendek328uedj

grant_type=refresh_token&
client_id=djc98u3jiedmi283eu928&
refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN
```

The repo below has some example javascript on how to do this:

```
https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js/blob/master/src/CognitoAuth.js#L473
```

Comment: Thank you, related documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

Comment: Hm, I found that in `Authorization` header I need to set `Base64Encode(client_id:client_secret)` - but I can not place `client_secret` to the js code for webbrowser?..